# Jackson Serializaiton/Deserialization by custom property in enum

Tags: kotlin, enums, jackson, deserialization

I want to make Jackson work with enums not by name and not by ordinal, but with a custom property I added called "stringId".
I wanted to support this with all Enums in the system so I made an interface called `StringIdEnum` which the FooEnum will implement.

I'm using Kotlin so I created a property in the interface called `stringId` which I override in each enum value.

Now I want to make Jackson serialize and deserialize using this stringId field, from what I seen I have several options:

1. Use `@JsonProperty` annotation on each enum value and make sure it is aligned with the stringId property.
   I see two issues with this approach. one it's a lot of annotation to add (we have many enum classes across the system). two I need to make sure the annotation value and the property value should be always the same which can cause issues in the future.
2. I tried to use the `READ_ENUMS_USING_TO_STRING` feature, but because I'm using an interface I can't override the toString in the interface class (I can override it in every enum class but that again seems like a lot of redundant code)
3. Implement a custom serializer/deserializer.
   The serializer is pretty straightforward, however, I had trouble with the deserializer.
   I wanted to register the deserializer on the StringIdEnum interface, but I had an issue getting all the runtime enum values for the actual FooType enum.

StringIdEnum:

```
interface StringIdEnum {

  val stringId: String
}
```

```
enum class FooType(override val stringId: String) : StringIdEnum {
   FOO("FOO"),
   GOO("GOO");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to get it working:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = StringIdEnumSerializer::class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = StringIdEnumDeserializer::class)
interface StringIdEnum: DbEnum {

  val stringId: String

}
```

```
class StringIdEnumSerializer: StdSerializer<StringIdEnum>(StringIdEnum::class.java) {

  override fun serialize(value: StringIdEnum, gen: JsonGenerator, provider: SerializerProvider) {
    gen.writeString(value.stringId)
  }

}
```

```
class StringIdEnumDeserializer : JsonDeserializer<Enum<*>>(), ContextualDeserializer {

  private lateinit var type: JavaType

  override fun deserialize(p: JsonParser, ctxt: DeserializationContext): Enum<*> {
    val t = p.text
    val enumConstants = (type.rawClass as Class<Enum<*>>).enumConstants
    return enumConstants.single { (it as StringIdEnum).stringId == t }
  }

  override fun createContextual(ctxt: DeserializationContext?, property: BeanProperty?): JsonDeserializer<*> {
    val wrapperType: JavaType = property!!.type
    val stringIdEnumDeserializer = StringIdEnumDeserializer()
    stringIdEnumDeserializer.type = wrapperType
    return stringIdEnumDeserializer
  }
}
```